# Connect to different mongo cluster from django restframework

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, database-migration

As I mentioned in the title my question is:

**Question:**

How to connect to different mongo cluster from Django rest framework?

Here are my `settings.py`:

```py
import mongoengine

TESTING = sys.argv[1:2] == ['test'] or get_env_var("TESTING", "FALSE").lower() == "true"

MONGO_DEFAULT_DB = 'my_default_db'

# def get_env_var(key, default):
#    return value of specified key from project env

MONGO_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS = {
    'username': get_env_var('MONGO_DEFAULT_USER', 'mongo_user'),
    'password': get_env_var('MONGO_DEFAULT_PASSWORD', 'mongo_passwd'),
}

MONGO_DATABASES = {
    'my_default_db': {
        'db': 'test' if TESTING else MONGO_DEFAULT_DB,
        'alias': 'default'
    },
    "another_db": {
        'db': 'test' if TESTING else 'another_db',
        'alias': 'another_db',
    }
}

MONGO_DEFAULT_URI = {
    'host': get_env_list('MONGO_SHARDED_HOSTS', [
        "127.0.0.1",
        "127.0.0.1",
        "127.0.0.1",
        "127.0.0.1",
    ]),
    'port': int(get_env_var('MONGO_PORT', 27017)),
}

for key in MONGO_DATABASES.keys():
    MONGO_DATABASES[key].update(MONGO_DEFAULT_URI)

    if not TESTING:
        MONGO_DATABASES[key].update(MONGO_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS)

# Mongo connection
for conn in MONGO_DATABASES.values():
    mongoengine.connect(**conn)
```

> `django 2.0.6` and `python 3.7`and `mongoengine 0.18.2` and `pymongo`

**Question:**

Is it a recommended way to connect to mongo?

**What I want to do:**

Actually, What I want is: to migrate data from the current mongo cluster to another mongo cluster and I want to transfer special data not the whole of them. and maybe a new mongo database isn't in a cluster. So

**My `mongo_model.py`:**

```py
from mongoengine.document import Document

class MyMongoModel(Document):
    # connected to current mongo cluster and I want to transfer data from this model to another mongo DB  
    pass
```

**My migration script is something like this:**

```py
data = MyMongoModel.objects.filter()

# connect to new mongo database and use bulk write to write on MyMongoModel collection
```

**Question:**

How can I change the database When I want to write data on the new mongo database?

> I know I can connect to the new mongo database like what I did for an old one but I want to know a better way to connect.